# Giving message according to if check

Tags: javascript

In a framework, i use below code. However, i always give success message

```
  if ($artistID)
                NCore::db('PERSON_MOVIE')->insertAsArray(array('PERSON_ID' => $artistID->id, 'MOVIE_ID' => $movieID, 'JOB_ID' => 374));
            else
                header('Location: http://www.sinemalar.com/management/artistAddEditRemove/');
```

This is the message

How can give a message according to else statement ? This is my js. What might be the changes?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMessage(a)
{
alert(a);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think it's a bit vague, your back end code seems to either redirect the user or save data in the database, it doesn't return any messages to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if(success=="a"){
    alert("Done")
    }else {
    alert("Something went wrong")
};
```